# How to Validate an Array of Objects and Sub-Objects using Express Validator Wildcards

Tags: express, validation, object, express-validator

I am trying to validate the data being passed with an array of objects in a JSON request. I used express-validator wildcards as specified in the documentation, but the error messages are returned irrespective of whether the properties of the objects are empty or not. I have checked various solutions online in an attempt to debug the issue, all to no avail. I will appreciate if anyone can point out what I am doing wrongly and suggest a correct solution, thanks.

The Validation

```
body("*.product", "Invalid or Empty Product Details").trim().notEmpty(),
body("*.price", "Invalid or Empty Product Price").trim().notEmpty(),
body("*.customer", "Invalid or Empty Customer Details")
   .trim()
   .notEmpty(),
body("*.seller", "Invalid or Empty Seller Details").trim().notEmpty(),
body("*.haulageOptions", "Invalid or Empty Haulage Options").trim().notEmpty()
```

The JSON Request

```
{
    "order": [
        {
            "product": {
                "commodity": "",
                "quantity": ""
            },
            "price": {
                "orderPrice": "",
                "deliveryPrice": "",
                "totalPrice": ""
            },
            "customer": {
                "name": "",
                "email": "",
                "location": {
                    "state": "",
                    "localGovernment": "",
                    "town": "",
                    "address": ""
                }
            },
            "seller": {
                "name": "",
                "phone": [
                    ""
                ],
                "email": ""
            },
            "haulageOptions": {
                "firstOrder": "",
                "secondOrder": "",
                "thirdOrder": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

The Validation

```
    check("order.*.product.commodity", "Empty Product Commodity").trim().notEmpty(),
    check("order.*.product.quantity", "Empty Product Quantity").trim().notEmpty(),
    check("order.*.price.orderPrice", "Empty Product Order Price").trim().notEmpty(),
    check("order.*.price.deliveryPrice", "Empty Product Delivery Price").trim().notEmpty(),
    check("order.*.price.totalPrice", "Empty Product Total Price").trim().notEmpty(),
    check("order.*.customer.name", "Empty Customer Name").trim().notEmpty(),
    check("order.*.customer.email", "Empty Customer Email").trim().notEmpty(),
    check("order.*.customer.location.state", "Empty Customer Location (State)").trim().notEmpty(),
    check("order.*.customer.location.localGovernment", "Empty Customer Location (Local Government)").trim().notEmpty(),
    check("order.*.customer.location.town", "Empty Customer Location (Town)").trim().notEmpty(),
    check("order.*.customer.location.address", "Empty Customer Location (Address)").trim().notEmpty(),
    check("order.*.seller.name", "Empty Seller Name").trim().notEmpty(),
    check("order.*.seller.phone", "Empty Seller Phone Number").trim().notEmpty(),
    check("order.*.seller.email", "Empty Seller Email Address").trim().notEmpty(),
    check("order.*.haulageOptions.firstOrder", "Empty Haulage Options").trim().notEmpty(),
```